# Problemas al leer un JSON

Tags: javascript, json

estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de recorrer un JSON.

Les muestro el código.

```
client.search(buscar).then(images => {
        let imgjson = JSON.stringify(images, ["url"], 4);

        METODO.PARA.MOSTRAR(imgjson);
    });
```

Bien, les explico. 
lo que hago es usar una api que me devuelve un json, le paso *buscar*, y recibo *images*.
Cuando muestro *images* así tal cual me sale [obj][obj], así que meto en *imgjson* el *JSON.stringify* con el dato que me interesa ("url"). Ahora cuando quiero mostrar el resultado de *imgjson* recibo lo siguiente

```
[
{
    "url": "http://www.vuescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Vue-JSON-Tree-View.png"
},
{
    "url": "https://www.w3resource.com/w3r_images/json-introduction.png"
}
]
```

(está acortado)
lo que recibo es exactamente lo que busqué, busqué la palabra "json" en google y recibí varias imagenes. 
Hasta ahora todo genial.

Podemos dar por hecho que (""imaginariamente"")

```
let imgjson = [
{
    "url": "http://www.vuescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Vue-JSON-Tree-View.png"
},
{
    "url": "https://www.w3resource.com/w3r_images/json-introduction.png"
}
];
```

¿verdad? 
porque el *JSON.stringify* es igual a eso.

Ahora, cuando quiero recorrer *imgjson* debería hacer

```
imgjson[0].url
```

y debería recibir el primer link del objeto.

El problema es que no recibo el primer link, sólo me salen undefineds.

Así sí funciona:

```js
let imgjson = [
    {
        "url": "http://www.vuescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Vue-JSON-Tree-View.png"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.w3resource.com/w3r_images/json-introduction.png"
    }
]

//METODO PARA MOSTRAR
document.write(imgjson[0].url)
```

Pero así no:

```
//hagamos de cuenta que recibo el JSON images
let imgjson = JSON.stringify(images, ["url"], 4);
//metodo para mostrar
document.write(imgjson[0].url);
```

esto ultimo muestra "undefined", pero *imgjson* muestra el json anteriormente dicho.

Perdón si fue un poco caotico, pero quiero asegurarme que se entienda.
¿alguien sabe por qué este último no funciona si en teoría el *let imgjson* es equivalente a el JSON?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Sin tener el valor original de la variable `images` es complicado saber qué es distinto.... puedes poner un ejemplo de ese valor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas interpretando mal como esta estructurado la variable `imgjson` que recibes ya que no necesitas hacer nada para obtener la url, solo debes llamarla sin hacer el `JSON.stringify()` y te mostrara al url. Cabe resaltar que [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) sirve para convertir un valor javascript a una cadena de JSON.

```js
//Solucion normal
let imgjson = [{
    "url": "http://www.vuescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Vue-JSON-Tree-View.png"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.w3resource.com/w3r_images/json-introduction.png"
  }
];

document.write(imgjson[0].url);

//Sino te funciona la solucion de arriba entonces prueba esta segunda que consiste 
// en parsear el resultado a un objeto por que tu result puedes ser una cadena Json
var images = '[{"url": "http://www.vuescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Vue-JSON-Tree-View.png"' +
  '},{"url": "https://www.w3resource.com/w3r_images/json-introduction.png"}]';

let jsonparse = JSON.parse(images);

document.write(jsonparse[0].url);
```